# Plotly Express: How to exclude specific dates from the X-axis after building a figure?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-express

I have a simple dataframe containing dates and a few headers. I need to remove specific dates from the plot.

```
fig1 = px.line(df, x=Date, y="Header1")
fig1.show()
```

I want to remove values from the chart itself (not from dataframe), like (removing 15/01/2022 & 22/02/2022).

date vs value plot
[image]

Comment: I think the best way is to create a copy `df_c = df.copy()` and then replace the unwanted values with `np.nan` and pass the new copy to plotly.

Comment: can not replace values, purpose it to remove points based on dates when outlier is observed.

Comment: How do you find these outliers?

Comment: What is the difference between the strategy mosc suggested (plot a cleaned-up copy) from your demand to remove the data points from the plot (whatever that means)? In both cases, you have your original data and a clean graph.

Comment: @DeepakB How did my suggestion work out for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would most likely rather do this ***with the dataset*** used to build your figure, instead of ***in the figure itself***. But this suggestion should do exactly what you're asking for. ***How*** you [find the outliers](http://Pandas:%20How%20to%20detect%20the%20peak%20points%20(outliers)%20in%20a%20dataframe?) will be entirely up to you. Given some thresholds `toolow, tohigh`, the snippet below will turn **Plot 1** into **Plot 2**

```
fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: highOutliers.extend([t.x[i] for i, val in enumerate(t.y) if val > toohigh]))
fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: lowOutliers.extend([t.x[i] for i, val in enumerate(t.y) if val < loolow]))

fig.update_xaxes(
    rangebreaks=[dict(values=highOutliers+lowOutliers)]
)

fig.update_traces(connectgaps=True)
```

#### Plot 1:

[image]

#### Plot 2:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
from numpy import random
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

# Some sample data
y = np.random.normal(50, 5, 15)
datelist = pd.to_datetime(pd.date_range(datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),periods=len(y)).tolist())
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':datelist, 'y':y})

# Introduce some outliers
df.loc[5,'y'] = 120
df.loc[10,'y'] = 2

# build figure
fig = px.line(df, x = 'date', y = 'y')

# containers and thresholds for outliers
highOutliers = []
lowOutliers = []
toohigh = 100
toolow = 20

# find outliers
fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: highOutliers.extend([t.x[i] for i, val in enumerate(t.y) if val > toohigh]))
fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: lowOutliers.extend([t.x[i] for i, val in enumerate(t.y) if val < toolow]))

# define outliers as rangebreaks
fig.update_xaxes(
    rangebreaks=[dict(values=highOutliers+lowOutliers)]
)

# connect gaps in the line
fig.update_traces(connectgaps=True)

fig.show()
```